# Can I unplug laptop display and use two external monitors?

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display

Will I be able to connect two monitors to my laptop with a HDMI splitter and extend the screen if my laptop display is physically unplugged from the motherboard?

Searching on Google, I find out that you can't extend your screen in Windows from a single HDMI output. But since my laptop screen is physically disabled (I literally unplugged the cable) from it’s source, I'd like to know if the splitter would do the job.

I know that I could just buy an USB/DisplayPort to HDMI/DVI/VGA adapter, but a splitter is way cheaper where I live.

Comment: Splitters do not allow multiple displays from a single output. At best you can have the same display on two screens, that's why they are cheap.

Comment: Nope. No chance unplugging your display is going to do anything. However, there are plenty of options for external displays via wireless, usb-c, etc. if your laptop does not have the proper number of ports.

Answer (score 0):

In general, No. You can't extend two screens with a splitter.
The splitter just copy the signal from one input to two or more outputs.

Using (or in your case, not using) the Laptop screen shouldn't change that behavior.

If you really want to mess with a splitter and monitors (and I would definitively avoid that) you might have a chance to send the image for the two monitors as one very width image and tell your monitors later to only use the left or the right part of the signal.